# Llamar a un MicroServicios de Spring Boot desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, post, http

tengo la siguiente duda ¿se puede llamar a un MicroServicios de Spring Boot desde JavaScript?

Tengo la siguiente función en JavaScript:

```
function confirmarRegiones() {
    var regiones = ["España", "Rusia"];
    //Solicitud HTTP
    ...
}
```

y quisiera enviar mediante una solicitud HTTP el array "regiones" a un MicroSevicio de Spring Boot.

La solicitud sería algo parecida a esta:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webResource = client.target("http://localhost:11708/regiones");

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webResource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response respuesta = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(regiones, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

pero en lenguaje JavaScript.

¿Cuál sería la forma mas eficiente de realizar esta acción?

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Lo común es hacerlo con xhr o ajax. Si el origen del script (js) es diferente del servidor al que estás haciendo el request adicionalmente vas a tener que configurar CORS en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Juan. He estado mirando y ahora tengo el siguiente problema. mi código en JavaScript es el siguiente:

```
function confirmarRegiones() {
var aux = regiones.join();
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: {'aux':aux},
       url: "confirmarregiones.html",
       success: function(msg){
         $('.answer').html(msg);
       }
   });
}
```

regiones es la variable array que deseo enviar. Sin embargo, desde el ServletController no se como recuperarla. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public String process(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    // La llamada desde JavaScript pasa por aquí sin problema
    System.out.println("Pasa por el ConfirmarRegionesHandler");
    
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    
    // Sin embargo, NO reconoce la variable 'aux'
    System.out.println(aux);
    
    return (String) session.getAttribute("rutaretorno"); 
}
```

La llamada desde JavaScript accede a la función sin problema pero NO reconoce la variable 'aux'.

¿Cuál es mi error? ¿Cómo debo indicarle al Controller cual es la variable que debe leer?